# (keras) I want to decay learning rate when val_acc stops improving

Tags: keras

I'm trying to make CNN model, but having low accuarcy :(

So, I want to decay SGD learning rate when validation accuracy stops improving.

How can I make and compile it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop on model.train_on_batch you can change the learning rate manually:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import sys

epochs = 50
batch_size = 32
iterations_per_epoch = len(x_train) // batch_size

lr = 0.01
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr), loss='some loss')

min_val_loss = sys.float_info.max
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in range(iterations_per_epoch):
        model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)
        val_loss = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val)
        if val_loss >= min_val_loss:
            K.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, lr / 2.)
            lr /= 2.
        else:
            min_val_loss = val_loss
```

This is a very naive way to decrease the learning rate once the validation loss had stopped decreasing. I would suggest implementing a bit more sophisticated rule such as validation loss had not decreased for the last X batches or so.

Comment: Since https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/36098bf0d7ca1e8285f63963130877746dc2809d#diff-1690a6925eefd029b3bebb7148e87612 it should be `model.optimizer.learning_rate`